# How can write a query like this using dblink in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, unique, archive, upsert, dblink

This is how my query looks -

```
INSERT INTO localdb_image select * from 
dblink('host=10.1.1.1
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=oat', 'SELECT e.* FROM image e JOIN archived f ON e.image_id=f.image_id AND e.dd=f.dd') tt(
      id int ,
  drive_id character varying(255) ,
 ) ;
```

I want to be able to run this query again but check if a row already exists, then do not insert anything. This will result in no errors of primary key already present if I run this query again.

Where can I add something like this in the query above?

```
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from localdb_image ei where ei.id = e.id)
```

The only thing that I can think of doing is just create a materialized view in the following manner:

```
create materialized view mv_localdb_image as select * from 
    dblink('host=10.1.1.1
     user=user
     password=password
     dbname=oat', 'SELECT e.* FROM image e JOIN archived f ON e.image_id=f.image_id AND e.dd=f.dd') tt(
          id int ,
      drive_id character varying(255) ,
     ) ;
```

And then refresh this periodically.

And insert in the localdb as following:

```
insert into localdb_image select * from mv_localdb_image mv where not exists (
select 1 from localdb_image ii where ii.id=mv.id)
```

Anyone know how we can achieve this directly without creating a materialized view and editing the first query I wrote above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column `id` is a primary key:

```
-- pseudocode
insert into localdb_image 
select *
from dblink(...) tt (...)
on conflict(id) do nothing;
```

If `id` is not a pk, create an index to make it unique. Your Postgres version must be 9.5+.

Comment: Is on conflict(id) faster than where not exists?

Comment: In most cases the performance should be similar but `on conflict()` may be a bit slower.